# Accelerometer doesn't work on iphone4

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, accelerometer

I use below code for accelerometer and it **works on ipod 3g** but **doesn't work on *iphone4*** (doesn't show alert)

.h

```
#define kAccelerationThreshold      2.2
#define kUpdateInterval         (1.0f/10.0f)
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIAccelerometer *accel=[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
    accel.delegate=self;
    accel.updateInterval=kUpdateInterval;
}

- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{
    if (fabsf(acceleration.x) > kAccelerationThreshold || fabsf(acceleration.y) > kAccelerationThreshold || fabsf(acceleration.z) > kAccelerationThreshold)
    {
         UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Shake" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
      [alert show];

    }
}
```

Comment: We'd need to see a lot more of your code - and a description of how exactly it doesn't work - to answer this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
accel=updateInterval=kUpdateInterval;
```

Looks like it should be

```
accel.updateInterval=kUpdateInterval;
```

Comment: this is my mistake here and i wrote it correct in xcode (It works on ipod means my code is correct)

Answer (score 1):

Copied your code into a new project - in order to get it to work I had to lower the `kAccelerationThreshold` value to around 1.5  - which still requires a fairly violent shake.

Only tested it on iPhone 4.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [UIAccelerometer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAccelerometer_Class/Reference/UIAccelerometer.html).

Be sure to also implement the `UIAccelerometerDelegate` protocol in your header.